# EntityFrameworkCore CurrentTransaction is Always null on SaveChangesAsync

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'd like to get `EfCore` database's `TransactionId` in `ISaveChangesInterceptor` implementation (triggered upon `DbContext.SaveChanges()` and `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()`)

For some reason the value for the `DbContext.Database.CurrentTransaction` is always `null`.

Am I missing something?

same behavior on `sqlite`, `SqlServer` and `SqlExpress`

```
    //Interceptor code:
    public class AuditSaveChangesInterceptor : ISaveChangesInterceptor
    {
       // code remove for readability...
        public async ValueTask<int> SavedChangesAsync(
            SaveChangesCompletedEventData eventData,
            int result,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
          // context.Database.CurrentTransaction is always null
         _record.TransactionId = context.Database.CurrentTransaction.TransactionId;
        }
    }

//dbContext 
 public class CatalogContext : DbContext
    {
        public CatalogContext(DbContextOptions<CatalogContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .HasMany(dm => dm.Categories)
                .WithMany();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .Navigation(e => e.Categories).AutoInclude();
        }
    }
    //db configuration:
    ...
services.AddDbContext<CatalogContext>((services, options) =>
{
    //    options.UseSqlite($"DataSource=catalog.db")
    options.UseSqlServer("<sql-server-connection-string>")
        .AddInterceptor(new AuditSaveChangesInterceptor());
});


//usage:
 using var context = CreateDbcontext() //psaudo for Dbcontext resolution
await context.AddRangeAsync(listOfProducts);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Where do you start your transaction?

Comment: @Progman - I do not declare transation, but rely on the default transactional behavior: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#default-transaction-behavior

Comment: Does it work when you use `ISaveChangesInterceptor.SavingChangesAsync()`? `ISaveChangesInterceptor.SavedChangesAsync()` is called when the save is complete, where most likely the transaction is already completed.

Comment: You need to begin a transaction, I believe.

Comment: @Progman both `SaveChanges` and `SaveChangesAsync` have null value for `CurrentTransaction`

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#default-transaction-behavior):

> By default, if the database provider supports transactions, all changes in a single call to `SaveChanges` are applied in a transaction. If any of the changes fail, then the transaction is rolled back and none of the changes are applied to the database. **This means that `SaveChanges` is guaranteed to either completely succeed, or leave the database unmodified if an error occurs**.

The docs does not claim that the transaction will be exposed to the database context (even more it does not make sense to, because the automatic transaction should be completed by the end of `SaveChanges`, and exposing it to end user will result in some inappropriate things which can be tried by the developer).

I believe that corresponding behavior (automatic transaction) can be found in [`BatchExecutor`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/00c6ac4f8b646e1dd22cd4e807fd64301895d44a/src/EFCore.Relational/Update/Internal/BatchExecutor.cs#L78) - it manages automatic transaction on connection level, not context one and does not set transaction in the context instance.

And the facade transaction APIs seems to be designed only for explicit developer usage, from [`DatabaseFacade.CurrentTransaction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade.currenttransaction?view=efcore-7.0) docs:

> This property is null unless one of `BeginTransaction()`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.BeginTransaction`, or `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.UseTransaction` has been called. No attempt is made to obtain a transaction from the current `DbConnection` or similar.

So if you want to get the transaction id via the `DbContext.Database.CurrentTransaction` you need to start a transaction explicitly - for example `context.Database.BeginTransaction()`.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [DatabaseFacade.CurrentTransaction Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade.currenttransaction?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-infrastructure-databasefacade-currenttransaction) states:

> Gets the current IDbContextTransaction being used by the context, or null if no transaction is in use.

The remarks section says:

> This property is null unless one of BeginTransaction(), Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.BeginTransaction, or Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.UseTransaction has been called. No attempt is made to obtain a transaction from the current DbConnection or similar.